# Is the Altap Salamander FTP client broken?

Tags: file-management

Was the [Altap Salamander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altap_Salamander) FTP client broken in later versions of 3.0.x? Is there a workaround?

I downloaded [the latest version of Altap Salamander](https://www.altap.cz/salamander/downloads/), 3.0.8 (2016-12-27), and set up the FTP client for a local FTP server (at 192.168.2.94).

When connecting I got this error dialog (yes, this was the literal message (slightly incomprehensible English)):

> Do you want to cancel getting of IP address of server? <kbd>Yes</kbd> <kbd>No</kbd>

#### Platform

- 32-bit micro PC (HANNspree), connected by Wi-Fi to a NAT router (192.168.2.1)

  - Intel Atom Bay Trail T-CR Z3735F. 1.33 GHz, quad core, 2 GB RAM, 32 GB eMMC
- Windows 8.1 (32-bit)

#### Observations

- At the same time the built-in FTP client in Windows Explorer (*not* Internet Explorer) was working fine, so it is probably not a firewall issue.
- At the same time I could access the local FTP server (at 192.168.2.94) from another Windows computer (different Windows version and with Altap Salamander 3.0.2 installed).
- The connections settings were set to use "passive" always (*Advanced* → *Use passive transfer mode (may help if you are behind firewall or proxy server)*).

#### What I tried to fix it

- I tried with another FTP site, on the Internet, that I have a lot of experience with (with a domain name, not IP address). It was also set to use passive transfers. It gave the same error. At the same time it worked fine from the other Windows computer.
- Eventually I uninstalled version 3.0.8 and installed 3.0.0 (32-bit). After this the FTP client worked fine. I could only do this because I have kept older versions around...

#### The FTP client plugin

[image]

#### The settings screen (for version 3.0.0)

[image: Screenshot of FTP client plugin]

Comment: Internet searches did not turn up anything even close to this problem (but it could be a [Google-fu](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Google-fu) problem).

Comment: May or may not be related: *[FTP settings gone again](https://forum.altap.cz/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=34127)* (on the Altap Salamander Support Forum)

Comment: There is detailed documentation for the FTP client plugin at *[Altap Salamander Help - Content](https://www.altap.cz/salamander/help/#a369)*, section *"FTP Client"*, with sub sections *"Using (sic!) FTP Client Plugin"* and *"Configuration"*.